# Showing that series converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the following converges:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1-\frac{e}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^ne^{t\sqrt{n}}}{n^{3/2}}$$
where $t$ is a parameter

(Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD7cn.jpg)

Comment: What $\;t\;$ are you talking about?

Comment: What convergence tests have you tried using?

Comment: t is located in exponent in e^t*sqrtn , I used Gauss test..

Comment: **Please**, say us what you have tried.

Comment: Help me to solve this, if you know ? Examine the convergence ...

Comment: Is Gauss test conclusive ?

Comment: Looks to me like $t>e$ gives divergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

$$\tag 1 (1-e/\sqrt n)^n = [(1-e/\sqrt n)^{\sqrt n}]^{\sqrt n}.$$

Now $(1-e/\sqrt n)^{\sqrt n}$ increases to $e^{-e}.$ Thus $(1)$ is bounded above by $(e^{-e})^{\sqrt n}.$ From this we see the $n$th term of your series is bounded above by

$$\tag 2 \frac{e^{(t-e)\sqrt n}}{n^{3/2}}.$$

If $t\le e,$ then $(2)$ is no more than $1/n^{3/2}.$ Hence the series converges by the comparison test. What happens if $t>e?$ I'll leave that to you for the moment.